# vertical offset for element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code

```
<div style="height:[Variable]px"></div>
<!--
or [ one or several div and section , with variable height ]
-->

<div class="Element" style="Position:relative">
     <div class="Pin"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

I need to get vertical offset for `$('.pin')` object , from top of my web page

So what would u guys suggest me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Pin_Offset $('.pin').offset().top
```

or
for variable div object

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

var Pin_Offset = $('.pin').offset().top + $(window).scrollTop()

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the offset of the ".pin" tag element to how far down the page the user has scrolled. The $(window).scroll() function will get you the amount the user has scrolled down so:

```
$(".select").click(function() {
  var pin = $('.pin');
  var top = offset.top;
  var bottom = $(window).height() - top - pin.height();
   bottom = bottom - offset.top; 

});
```

i hope its help